# Interface Method Called in Class Constructor

Tags: java

Could someone explain in the following example why the interface method can be called directly when it is passed as a parameter in a class constructor? I try to search a rule in the Java language specification but can not find one.

```
public interface Interface {
    public void foo();
}

public class Main {
    public Main() {}
    public Main(Interface obj) {obj.foo();}
    public static int test() {return 123;}
}
```

Comment: Why would it *not* be callable?

Comment: Inteface obj is just the reference variable, is referencing in a concrete implementation, that's why you are confused i think

Answer (score 3):

Is just a polymorphic behaviour, Java expects an implementation of the method of that interface.
That means, any class which implements that method is an `Interface`, so you can have many many different implementations of that method.
Let's say:

```
public class ImplementedInterface implements Interface
{
    public void foo()
    {
        System.out.println("Hey!, i'm implemented!!");
    }
}
```

So when you call:

```
Interface aux = new ImplementedInterface();
Main m = new Main(aux);
```

The text "Hey!, i'm implemented!!" will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `foo` method from `Interface` reference because it can hold only object of class that implements `Interface`, so it will provide body for `foo` method.

Now thanks to late binding Java will use code of object class when needed.

Comment: i don't like point is like a pointer , instead use referencing that would be more suitable for a reference xD

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are confused, you think cuase it's Interface type it's an interface

```
public Main(Interface obj) {
  obj.foo();
}
```

obj is an object from a concrete implementation of `Interface`.

You may want to see some common design pattern that take this approach such as `Strategy Pattern`

For example :

```
public interface Searcher {
  void search(String text, List<String> words);
}

public class BinarySearcher implements Searcher{
   @Override
   public void search(String text , List<String> words){
      //code here
   }

}

public class LinearSearcher implements Searcher{
     @Override 
     public void search(String text ,List<String> words ){
           // code here
     }
}

public class WordContext {

private Searcher searcher;
private List<String> words;

public void makeSearch(String text){
    searcher.search(); // you only know at runtime what subtype will be searcher
}

// here you inject by contract
public void setSearcher(Searcher searcher){
  this.searcher= searcher;
}

// here you inject by contract
public void setWords(List<String> words){
   this.words = words;
}

}
```

That's the main advantage you guide by abstract contract instead of concrete implementation.
In this example you can change the searcher injecting it, can be a linearSearcher or a binarySearcher, that's the polymorphic magic!

Answer (score 0):

Here is where `Programming to an interface, not an implementation` comes into play. Your method is expecting an object of the class that that implements the `interface`

I would explain it with an example.

Let us say I have 
    `LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();`

and I have
    `ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();`

Now I have a method -

```
public void deleteFirst(List aList) {
  System.out.println(aList.remove(0));
 }
```

Now you can pass both `ll` and `al` to the `deleteFirst` method. Which means your method is passed an object of the class that that implements the `interface`.

In the example `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` both implement the `List` interface and therefore can be passed to the method. Ultimately what your method is getting is an object of the class that implements the `List` interface.

Comment: You should hold on before posting an answer then. Don't post until it's useful. I still don't think it actually answers the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Does it make sense now?

Comment: It's better, yes. (It's an odd question to start with, to be honest - the OP hasn't shown anything about why he's surprised it works.)